# Laravel Query Builder with polymorphic joins not working on SQLite

Tags: mysql, laravel, sqlite, polymorphism, group-concat

I have a big Laravel Query Builder query and here is the minimal version of it

```
$query = DB::table('trainings')
            ->select(
                'trainings.id as training_id as training_id',
                'taggables.id as taggables_id',
                'taggables.tag_id as taggables_tag',
                'tags.id as tags_id',
                DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(tags.category) as tags_category'),
                DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(tags.value) as tags_value')
            )
            ->join('taggables', function($join) {
                $join->on('taggables.taggable_id', 'trainings.id')
                    ->where('taggables.taggable_type', 'App\\Training')
                ;
            })
            ->leftjoin('tags','tags.id','=','taggables.tag_id')
            ->groupBy('trainings.id')
            -get()
            ;
```

which generates this sql:

```
select trainings.id as training_id,
taggables.id as taggables_id, 
taggables.tag_id as taggables_tag, 
tags.id as tags_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.category) as tags_category, 
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.value) as tags_value 

from trainings 

inner join taggables on taggables.id = trainings.id and taggables.taggable_type = "App\\Training"
left join tags on tags.id = taggables.tag_id 

group by trainings.id
```

and the results is:

[image]

When i'm running the same code on phpunit test (with different data + sqlite) the results looks like this:

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#2579
    +"training_id": "2"
    +"taggables_id": "1"
    +"taggables_tag": "{"value":1,"category":1,"id":1}"
    +"tags_id": null
    +"tags_category": null
    +"tags_value": null
  }
]
```

For some reason "taggables_tag" returns JSON/object of the related tags table data and also the tags_ -fields are empty (probably because the last join is not working).

Any ideas how to fix this?

*UPDATE*

The problem is the join, not group_concat:

```
$query = DB::table('trainings')
            ->join('taggables', function($join) {
                $join->on('taggables.taggable_id', 'trainings.id')
                    ->where('taggables.taggable_type', 'App\\Training')
                ;
            })
            ->get()

Returns:
    +"tag_id": "{"value":1,"category":1,"organisation_id":1,"updated_at":"2020-01-20 10:29:56","created_at":"2020-01-20 10:29:56","id":1}"
    +"taggable_id": "2"
    +"taggable_type": "App\Training"
```

Comment: plz post your query...

Comment: added the query builder query

Comment: I think you need to use `->toSql()` and see the raw sql that query generated.And r u `dd($query)`?

Comment: The raw sql is already there :) "which generates this sql:"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by:

```
// running tests (SQLite) returns json of the related mode
if (App::environment() === 'testing') {
    $query->addSelect('taggables.tag_id->value as taggables_tag_id');
} else {
    $query->addSelect('taggables.tag_id as taggables_tag_id');
}
```

and changing the last leftjoin to `->leftjoin('tags','tags.id','=','taggables_tag_id')`